# Reflexivity on the gt relation in Coq

Tags: relationship, coq

I want to prove that for any natural number n+1 is greater than 0.

Defining my own greater than function this works fine:

```
Fixpoint my_gt (n : nat) (m : nat) : bool
  := match n with
     | O    => false
     | S n' => match m with
               | O    => true
               | S m' => my_gt n' m'
               end
     end.

Lemma GT1: forall n, my_gt (S n) O = true. reflexivity. Qed.
```

But when I use the default ">"-relation Coq refuses with the message "Tactic failure: The relation gt is not a declared reflexive relation. Maybe you need to require the Setoid library". Because I do require the Setoid library I don't understand why Coq does not seem to find the gt definition?

```
Require Export Coq.Setoids.Setoid.
Lemma GT2: forall n, S n > O. reflexivity.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at Coq's `gt` definition, you will this that it is just a notation over `lt`, which is a notation over `le`:

```
    gt = fun n m : nat => m < n
         : nat -> nat -> Prop

    lt = fun n m : nat => S n <= m
         : nat -> nat -> Prop

    Inductive le (n : nat) : nat -> Prop :=
        le_n : n <= n | le_S : forall m : nat, n <= m -> n <= S m
```

Now as you can see, it is not declared as a function, but as an inductive predicate, so you cannot simply "compute" to get the solution. To prove such a goal, you will have to use tactics such as `constructor` and `induction` to prove your goal.

Note that your relation is in `bool` whereas Coq's is in `Prop` (the general way to compare two elements of some type might no be decidable). For the particular case of natural numbers, you can find `leb` somewhere in the `Arith` module, which behaves as you except:

```
    Require Import Arith.
    Print leb.

    Lemma GT2: forall n, leb O (S n) = true.
    reflexivity.
    Qed.
```

Best,
V.

Comment: Thanks: I now defined `Lemma GT2: forall n, S n > O. induction n.  constructor. constructor. auto. Qed.`